# runtime check failure #2-stack around the variable x2 was corrupted

Tags: c, variables, stack, runtime

I ve written this program to calculate the solutions of 3X3 system of linear equations using the cramer rule. The program works and outputs correct results but before it ends normally it is prompted an error message "Run time check failure #2-stack around the variable x2 was corrupted" and the program does not terminate correctly. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cramer (double** a, double* b);

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    double** a;
    double* b;
    a=(double**)malloc(3*sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        a[i]=(double*)malloc(3*sizeof(double));
    b=(double*)malloc(3*sizeof(double));
printf ("This program computes the solutions of a system of linear equations 3X3\n");
printf ("a11x1+a12x2a13x3=b1\n");
printf ("a21x2+a22x2+a23x3=b2\n");
printf ("a31x3+a32x2+a33x3=b3\n");
printf ("Insert a and b\n");
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
    for (j=0;j<3;j++){
    printf("a%d%d\n",i+1,j+1);
    scanf("%lf",&a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("b%d\n",i+1);
    scanf("%lf",&b[i]);
}
cramer(a,b);
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
    free(a[i]);
free(a);
free(b);
return 0;
}

void cramer(double** a,double* b)
{
int i,j;
double x1[3][3],x2[3][3],x3[3][3],A[3][3];
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
    for (j=0;j<3;j++){
    A[i][j]=a[j][i];
    x1[i][j]=a[i][j]*A[i][j];
    x2[i][j]=a[i][j]*A[i][j];
    x3[i][j]=a[i][j]*A[i][j];
    }
    x1[i][1]=b[i];
    x2[i][2]=b[i];
    x3[i][3]=b[i];
}
    printf("   %f %f %f\n",x1[0][0],x1[0][1],x1[0][2]);
    printf("x1=%f %f %f\n",x1[1][0],x1[1][1],x1[1][2]);
    printf("   %f %f %f\n",x1[2][0],x1[2][1],x1[2][2]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("   %f %f %f\n",x2[0][0],x2[0][1],x2[0][2]);
    printf("x2=%f %f %f\n",x2[1][0],x2[1][1],x2[1][2]);
    printf("   %f %f %f\n",x2[2][0],x2[2][1],x2[2][2]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("   %f %f %f\n",x3[0][0],x3[0][1],x3[0][2]);
    printf("x3=%f %f %f\n",x3[1][0],x3[1][1],x3[1][2]);
    printf("   %f %f %f\n",x3[2][0],x3[2][1],x3[2][2]);
}
```

Comment: It is an excellent diagnostic that tells you that you are indexing an array out-of-bounds.  Out jumps `x3[i][3]=b[i];`, the last valid index is 2.

Comment: @HansPassant Mathematicians should not be allowed to touch computers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
x1[i][1]=b[i];
x2[i][2]=b[i];
x3[i][3]=b[i];   // index is out of range
```

Probably this is what you mean:

```
x1[i][0]=b[i];
x2[i][1]=b[i];
x3[i][2]=b[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
x3[i][3]=b[i];
```

is accessing memory beyond the bounds of the array you defined. C has zero based indexing, so for your 3x3 arrays the maximum valid index is 2.

Probably should have

```
x1[i][0]=b[i];
x2[i][1]=b[i];
x3[i][2]=b[i];
```